# button in contentplaceholder web application(asp.net4) doesn't fire

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I created a Master Page in asp.net web application.  In the `contentplaceholder`, I have a button, but when rendering the page, and then clicking on the button, it doesn't fire.

How do I it?

Thanks a lot.

```
       <asp:Content ID="Content2"      ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"runat="server" >   

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1"  runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">        
    <asp:Button ID="Button1"  Text="register" ForeColor="Blue" Font-Bold="true"  Font-Names="tahoma" Font-Size="Medium" Height="40px" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

and in the `default.aspx.designer.cs` :

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Button1;
```

Button1_Click:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page; 
    Boolean re = SDKClass.News_InsertNew(
        Subject_News_textbox.Text.ToString(),
        Brief_News_textbox.Text.ToString(), 
        CKEditor1.Text.ToString(), 
        date_now_textbox.Text, 
        "Image1", 
        true); 
    if (re == true) 
    { 
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "message", "alert(' register news')", true); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Show your code for the `Button1_Click` method.

Comment: I would suggest removing the tag asp.net-web-api and instead using tag asp-net.

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

            Boolean re = SDKClass.News_InsertNew(Subject_News_textbox.Text.ToString(), Brief_News_textbox.Text.ToString(), CKEditor1.Text.ToString(), date_now_textbox.Text, "Image1", true);
            if (re == true)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "message", "alert(' register news')", true);

            }  
        }

Comment: I've edited your post to include the `Button1_Click` code.  In most cases you should do the same (edit your post to include the requested code) because code does not format very well in comments.

Comment: Thanks David , But what's the solution?

Comment: Could you please try to add `CausesValidation="False"` to markup for your button definition to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Thanks , but button doesn't fire

Comment: really , any programmer ( web application developer) aren't there to solve the problem.